# Forwarding of return types of CRTP-derived class methods

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp, perfect-forwarding, static-polymorphism

I want to use "static polymorphism" via CRTP to do something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    double get_value() const { return ((T*)this)->_get_value(); }

protected:
    ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>
{
    double value;

    Derived1() : value(3.) {}

    const double& _get_value() const { return value; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>
{
    double _get_value() const { return 5.; }
};
```

This works, but I'd also like that for the case of the object being instantiated as `Derived1`, `get_value` returns a const reference to the value instead of returning a copy. So in a way, a kind of "perfect forwarding" for return values.

I tried to declare `get_value`'s return type like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    decltype(std::declval<T>()._get_value()) get_value() const { return ((T*)this)->_get_value(); }
    ...
```

but unsurprisingly GCC complained that this is an `invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Derived1'`.

Is there any way to go around this?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: There's an interesting difference in behaviour between gcc and clang regarding the protected destructor: https://godbolt.org/z/W6M8Mo
Maybe you want to ask another question about that (I'd be interested as well) - Edit: ah, that's only in C++20 but not in C++11 mode o.O

Answer (score 4):

The reason why GCC is rejecting the proposed solution in the OP is that `Base<Derived1>` is being instantiated *before* `Derived1`. This instantiation consists of an instantiation of the signatures of all member functions, but it doesn't instantiate the function bodies themselves.

So we need to defer determination of the signature/return type of the member function until *after* `Derived1` is visible.

One way to do this is by deferring determination of the return type via `decltype(auto)`. This makes the return type dependent on the function body (which is not immediately instantiated). It's a C++14 feature, unfortunately.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    decltype(auto) get_value() const { return ((T*)this)->_get_value(); }

protected:
    ~Base() {}
};
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/r1T56n

---

This is probably covered by [dcl.spec.auto](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.spec.auto.general-12) and [temp.inst](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#inst-3).

---

Alternatively, even in C++11, you can postpone determination of the return type by turning the function into a function template, dependent on some dummy parameter if necessary:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    template<typename U=T>
    decltype(std::declval<U>()._get_value()) get_value() const {
        return ((T*)this)->_get_value();
    }

protected:
    ~Base() {}
};
```

Comment: I hope I got my instantiation order right, I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: Perfect, I used your solution #2 and it worked exactly as needed. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @PabloGrube I think `decltype(auto)` is the more conventional way of perfectly forwarding return types. The main difference to the `declval` construct is that the `declval` thing is SFINAE-friendly.

Comment: Unfortunately `auto` return types don't exist before C++14, and the question is tagged [c++11] :)

Comment: @Quentin Ah thanks, I thought I've tested that with `-std=c++11`...